# Why is PHP not recognizing a program in the Windows System PATH when I use it with Apache?

Tags: php

In my local development environment, I have Apache and PHP installed on Windows 7. I'm calling 7-Zip from my PHP program with exec. I tried at first with

```
exec('7z a example.zip example.pdf');
```

but it didn't create the zip file. After checking the Apache error log, I found

> '7z' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

After changing the `exec` to include the full path to 7-Zip.exe, it worked.

```
exec('"C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z" a example.zip example.pdf');
```

But `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` is included in my Windows system PATH. The same PHP code works from the command line without using the full path.

```
php -r "exec('7z a example.zip example.pdf');"
```

Why is it requiring the full path when I use it with Apache?

---

An important point which I neglected to include when I originally posted this question is that I am already able to use `exec()` to call other programs included in the Windows System PATH without referring to them by their full paths.

Another point which I did not mention originally because I did not realize its relevance was that 7-Zip had been added to the PATH only recently, and I had restarted the Apache service after adding it.

Comment: Apache isn't running from your account, it doesn't have your `PATH` settings.

Comment: @Barmar I thought putting it in the system `PATH` rather than my user `PATH` would take care of that. Is that not how that works?

Comment: ... you should try `/usr/bin/7z`

Comment: @hek2mgl this is a windows machine not linux

Comment: oh, then it should be `C:\\Programs\WhatEver\7z`

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, I did that and it did work. I'm just trying to figure out why it needs to be done that way.

Comment: This happens because `apache` clears it's environment on startup. You can use `setEnv` in `.htaccess` or `putenv` in PHP code to set `$PATH`

Comment: @Barmar Check this ^^^. This is not really related to an account IMHO.

Comment: Could you guys please comment on my answer ? specifically, "__I've no idea why this is happening and if someone has a clue please comment below.__"

Comment: @PedroLobito I think the comment from hek2mgl helps explain it. I've been reading about [Environment Variables in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html) to try to understand it better.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I just saw it now... I guess that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out what was causing this problem. It was actually unrelated to my original assumption.

I remembered seeing `PATH` information in `phpinfo()`, so I looked at that. In the "Apache Environment" section it did show all of the `PATH` *except* the path to 7-Zip, which I had just added to the system `PATH` recently. So apparently it DOES seem to have access to that path, but it wasn't using the current version of it. Why not?

Normally I would think I had just forgotten to restart Apache after updating the path, but I'd restarted it repeatedly while trying to figure this out. But apparently **restarting** Apache does not refresh this value. I had to **stop** it and then **start** it. Then the 7-Zip path showed up in `PATH` in phpinfo, and I was able to change my program back to using plain `7z`.

Answer (score 3):

I've WAMP installed on windows 8 and after reading your question I decided to test a couple of things.

Running `echo exec('whoami');` echoed:

```
nt authority\system
```

This confirms what [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said, Apache isn't running under the same user as you, so, the `PATH` is different.

I decided to stop Apache and start it manually under the Administrator account.
Then I tried:

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

Which outputted:

```
computername\administrator
```

I assumed that now the `exec` would work with `PATH` and tried:

`echo exec('adb');` //android adb tool is on my `PATH`

Surprisingly, despite the fact Apache was running with the same user as me, the `PATH` still didn't work. I've no idea why this is happening and if someone has a clue please comment below.

I managed to use the `PATH` (using the Administrator account) with the following code:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl
    $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
    $oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd /C 7z a example.zip example.pdf", 0); // 0 invisible /  1 visible

---

<strike>I didn't test the code below, but you can try setting the `PATH` under the Apache Service account (`nt authority\system`), and then use the command, i.e.:</strike>

```
echo exec('set PATH=%PATH%;C:/path/to/7z');
echo exec('7z a example.zip example.pdf');
```

I believe the `path` will still be valid between restarts.

---

## Update:

[this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/102801/92233), may help you setting the `PATH` for the account `nt authority\system`.

> The Local System user's personal environment variables are specified
>   at "**HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Environment**". The machine-wide environment
>   variables are specified at
>   "**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
>   Manager\Environment**". The former isn't really easily accessible from
>   anywhere except the registry, but the latter is accessible from the
>   "**Environment Variables**" dialog on the "**Advanced**" tab of the "**System
>   Properties**".

---

For future users, the correct way to set the Apache PATH is:

> You can use `setEnv` in `.htaccess` or `putenv` in `PHP` code to set
>   `$PATH`

Credit goes to [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl)

Comment: the path will not be valid between restarts here, that is only for the running session. you will need to set your environment variables elsewhere. this line shows an example of that: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I assumed the path of `Administrator` isn't the same as `nt authority\system`, so, setting the path as instructed won't solve the problem.

Comment: @PedroLobito I discovered the actual cause of this. I added an answer to describe it. I think after all it was just me not understanding Apache properly. Thanks for your interest, and sorry if I wasted your time here.