# 7zip command executes from command line but not within php script

Tags: php, command-line, command, 7zip

I am attempting to write a script which automatically unzips 7zip archives.  I'm able to get the command to run from the command prompt, but it doesn't work when running from within the php script.

Here's what I have in terms of code:

```
$filefolder = "F:/dev/";
$filename = "archive.7z";
$filepath = $filefolder . $filename;

$unzip = "cmd /c 7z x " . $filePath . " -o" . $fileFolder . " -spf";
print_r($unzip . "<br>"); //checking to make sure the command is formed correctly
exec($unzip, $outcome, $rtnStatus);
print_r($outcome);
print_r($rtnStatus);
```

The following is returned for $outcome and $rtnStatus:

```
Array ( ) 
1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you mean within a CLI php script or a web script?

Comment: It's a web script.

Comment: The webserver user doesn't know where `7z` is: `c:/some path/to/7z`

Comment: An explanation of what specifically **doesn't work** means?

Comment: Ken - in the command line, the archive extracts the files like it's supposed to.  In the script, nothing happens.

Comment: Have you added 7z to your system path?

Comment: I had some trouble with that a while back. You can see if [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981010/why-is-php-not-recognizing-a-program-in-the-windows-system-path-when-i-use-it-wi) is helpful at all.

Comment: Don't Panic - I took another look and yes, I did add 7z to the system path.  Before I did, I couldn't even run 7zip from the command line.